# docker-compose command bash: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this problem when i start the docker-compose. The file app.sh exist but the docker is not finding. How i can fixed this bug?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  dados:
services:
    db:
      image: postgres:9.6
      volumes:
        - dados:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - /c/Users/Youssef/Documents/curso/email-worker-compose/scripts:/scripts
        - /c/Users/Youssef/Documents/curso/email-worker-compose/scripts/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    frontend:
      image: nginx:1.13
      volumes:
         - /c/Users/Youssef/Documents/curso/email-worker-compose/web:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      ports:
      - 80:80
   app:
     image: python:3.6
     volumes:
       - ./app:/app
     working_dir: /app
     command: bash ./app/app.sh
     ports:
       - 8080:8080
```

Logs:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "emailworkercompose_default" with the default driver
Creating emailworkercompose_app_1      ... done
Creating emailworkercompose_db_1       ... done
Creating emailworkercompose_frontend_1 ... done
Attaching to emailworkercompose_frontend_1, emailworkercompose_app_1, emailworkercompose_db_1
app_1       | bash: app.sh: No such file or directory
db_1        | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-06-04 14:26:01 UTC
db_1        | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1        | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
emailworkercompose_app_1 exited with code 127
```

app.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
pip install bottle==0.12.13 psycopg2==2.7.1 redis==2.10.5
python -u sender.py
```

Comment: Your slashes are in the opposite direction in the command section. Could that be the source of the issue?

Comment: Please post formatted text of code and logs, not pictures of code and logs.

Comment: I traded everyone for the two sides and not solved the problem,

Answer (score 0):

Check slashes and make file executable.

Comment: I traded everyone for the two sides and not solved the problem

Comment: Did you make it executable?

Comment: Try to open folder with app.sh within git console and run bash app.sh and share output

Comment: $ bash ./app/app.sh
     ./app/app.sh: line 2: pip: command not found
     ./app/app.sh: line 3: python: command not found

Comment: In your git console evironment pip and python don't exist or don't added to PATH

Comment: You should to export path to pip and python binary to your git console environment.

Comment: I tried in other pc and works this code, im gonna reinstall the docker and try again this code.

Comment: Ok. Give it a try. Your other pc is also using Windows?